# Moving std::istream

Tags: c++, move, fstream, iostream, istream

I have a `Scanner` class to tokenize streams of characters coming from files, `cin`, etc.

```
class Scanner {
public:
  Scanner(std::istream&& c) : input{std::move(c)} {}

private:
  std::istream input;
};
```

This code does not compile because the move constructor of `std::istream` is protected. I could use a reference to the stream instead, but then, I have no guarantee that someone is not playing with my stream outside of the `Scanner` class (`ss` below).

```
  std::string code = "this is code";
  std::stringstream ss{code};
  Scanner scanner{ss};
```

Is there a neat way to address this issue, or do people just use `std::istream&` and hope for the best?

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to take ownership of the stream

Comment: Well, you can't use std::istream&. The object will not live.

Comment: If you want to move the stream, then *move the stream*, not some reference through an abstract base class. You can move the concrete object itself (in this case, the `std::istringsream`). But trying to move an abstract base class reference is nonsense. That's not how move works. if `input` is `std::istringstream`, and the argument is `std::istringstream&& c`, your code will be much happier.

Comment: Yes, but I was trying to get a scanner that also works for std::ifstream, cin, etc. If I change input to std::istringstream, that no longer works.

Comment: @WhozCraig But that's not what he's trying to achieve here.

Comment: @0xbaadf00d That's what I first tried, but it does not compile because the copy constructor of std::istream is deleted. That's why I was going for move semantics in the first place, assuming it was because of some buffer issues.

Comment: @Touloudou I understand that, but my point is you're not understanding how move semantics *work*. You don't move references; rather, you use references to accomplish moving. An alternative *may* be to write different overloads, then setup a `std::unique_ptr<std::istream>` member that instantiates a concrete object of the appropriate type (`std::ifstream`, `std::istringstream`, etc), and move the providing argument in as a construction arg. It *should* work, but will still leave you without support for `std::cin`. Now that I think about it, that won't work either. No virtual destruction etc.

Comment: @WhozCraig I am not very familiar with C++ streams, but that's not what I was expecting. I don't expect the move constructor to move the underlying object (the `std::string` or whatever). However, I expected it to move the current state of the `std::istream` (e.g. current location in the `std::string`). Does `std::istream` not have a state? Is it just a reference to the base object?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can remember about my work with stream objects.

You need to think about this a bit differently.

```
class Scanner {
public:
  Scanner() {}
  virtual void scan(std::istream & p_stream);
};
```

Your Scanner class could just be focused on scanning the input for whatever, not actually containing it.

Now it can be focused purely on a single task.

Then you need to work out what is the best way for you to keep the stream object alive. I suggest a separate class for that task.

I would have written this as a comment, but there's too much here.

Comment: Yes, this was plan B. I was just unhappy with the reference. Thanks though. However, why a virtual function?

Comment: Ah, just an afterthought. You might want to make multiple different scanners, to look for different things. Then a Scanner that contains all those scanners and runs them in sequence or something. (to look for multiple things)

Comment: In addition to your own custom logic scanner, you might want to make a regex scanner (give the regex as a parameter?) and an XML scanner. But maybe that's too much for what you are making.

Comment: Go and look at "Composite design pattern". I'm pretty sure the internet has a better explanation than me.